# Run sqlite3 command from batch file?

Tags: android, batch-file

I want to make it easier to access the sqlite databases on the emulator, so I've created a batch file that successfully runs the first line, but is there a way to run the second line from the batch file? (At this point adb is already running, so it would be running a command in the shell.)

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.myProject/databases/myDatabase
```

---

UPDATE:
For some reason

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.myProject/databases/myDatabase
```

prevents you from using the command line.  Typing and pasting both seemed to be blocked.  I ran this line in a command line outside of the batch and it does the same thing.

Separate lines work fine:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell 
sqlite3 /data/data/com.myProject/databases/myDatabase
```

but this doesn't work in the batch file (the sqlite3 command gets executed too early).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run specific commands other than just an interactive shell on the target device. eg:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell ls /sdcard
```

or

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell sqlite3 /data/data/com..../database.db
```

Once it gets complicated, it might be better to use a script that you copy over onto the device and run on demand.

Comment: Use the `;` separator to send multiple commands. Like this: `adb -s emulator-5554 shell ls /sdcard; ls /data`

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for (I didn't know it was that simple).  Only problem--I can't type into the terminal window.  Does the batch file have a lock on the process?

Comment: Does anyone know why I can't type into the terminal window. Does the batch file have a lock on the process?  I want to be able to then use the terminal window for sql queries.

Comment: Confirmed. I guess when you specify a command (like `sqlite3`) in the command line, ADB does not bother to process input. Interactive commands were not meant to be called that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use input redirection to send a stream of commands to ADB:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell <a.txt
```

Where `a.txt` contains

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.myProject/databases/myDatabase
logout
```

This scales better. a.txt can grow as big as you want.